# how to export all the records of a table from snowflake?

Tags: export, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to export the data of a table in Snowflake into excel or csv file. Can I directly get the **data into my local machine** without any staging like S3 bucket or similar?

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007vugVV/can-i-unload-data-directly-from-a-query-to-a-local-file-without-staging-to-s3-or-azure

Answer (score 3):

If your table is too big to query in the UI and download the results to a CSV or Tab-delimited file, then you'll need to leverage COPY INTO {location} as your Snowflake-native solution to get data out.  You can leverage Snowflake's internal staging, if you don't have your own S3 bucket and then leverage SnowSQL to "GET" the file from internal stage to your local machine.

For more information, https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-summary-unloading.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's small enough that you don't mind the single stream download, you could write a little program to make this happen.  Like a little python utility that leverages the snowflake connector to run your query and turn the data into a local csv.

Comment: If you plan to write something in Python, I'd recommend leveraging the Python connector, not the JDBC connector.  And this would be a much slower method than installing SnowSQL and using a COPY INTO.

Comment: yes good point of clarity, that's actually what i meant!  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can export up to 1M rows directly into excel with the Snowflake ODBC connector:
1) install ODBC driver
2) configure driver with snowflake creds
3) open excel and go to data->get data-> other sources - > odbc